# Issue with collisions between two objects of the same class with collide2d library

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am currently working on creating a pong-like game in p5.js. So far almost everything has been working perfectly, however, with the addition of a feature where an additional player paddle, opponent paddle, and ball are created after reaching a certain score, I am having an issue.

Previously collisions with this collide2d library for p5.js between the player's paddle and the ball had been working perfectly. After the second paddle is added though, collisions are only working between the ball and their respective paddles. As in, the initial paddle can only hit the ball you started with, and the new paddle cannot hit the original ball.

For the sake of this post, I have made the original ball white, and the new ball black. Here is my code:

```js
things=[];
var hit=false;
let y=0;
let b=0;
let s=4;
let i=0;
let l=5;
let STARTSCREEN=1;
let GAME=2;
let mode;


function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  let p1=new Thing(0,0,0,255);
  things.push(p1);
  mode = STARTSCREEN;
}

function draw() {
  if (mode == STARTSCREEN) {
    startScreen();
  } else if (mode == GAME) {
    game();
  } 
}



function startScreen() {
  background(255, 194, 209);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  noStroke();
  fill(255, 229, 236);
  rect(width/2, height/2, width/2, height/6) // start button box
  
  fill(255, 179, 198);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  textSize(33);
textFont('IBM Plex Mono');
  text("CLICK TO START", width / 2, height / 2 + 10);
  
  fill(255, 229, 236);
  text("HIGH SCORE:", width / 2, height / 6);
  text(b, width / 2, height / 6 * 1.5);
  
  textSize(23);
  text("(ONLY PROS GET PAST 25!)", width / 2, height / 6 * 1.9);
  
  textSize(50);
  text("PONG PERFECT", width / 2, height / 6 * 4.75)
  textSize(23);
  text("CAN YOU BEAT THE PERFECT AI?", width / 2, height / 6 * 5.25);
  
}

function startClicks() {
  mode = GAME;
}

function mousePressed() {
  if (mode === STARTSCREEN) {
    startClicks();
  } else if (mode === GAME) {
    gameClicks();
  }
}




function game() {
  background(255, 194, 209);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  fill(255, 229, 236);
  rect(width/2, height / 8, 100, 50) // score box
  textSize(35);
  noStroke();
  fill(255, 229, 236);
  rect(width/2, height/2, 5, height); // middle line
  rectMode(CORNER);
    fill(255, 194, 209);
  textFont('Press Start 2P');
  text(s, width / 2, height / 8+12); // score
  for(let thing of things) {
    thing.move();
    thing.collide();
    thing.show();


  }
  


  
}

function keyPressed() {
  if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW)) y+=l;
  if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)) y-=l;
}


class Thing {
  constructor(x,y,z,c) {
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.z=z;
    this.f=60;
    this.c=c;
    this.w=width/2;
    this.h=height/2;
    this.speedX=5;
    this.speedY=5;
  }
  
  show() {
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 229, 236);
    //player
    rect(0+20, this.y, 10, this.f);
    
    //opponent
    rect(width-30, this.z, 10, 60);
    
    //ball
    fill(this.c);
    rect(this.w, this.h, 10, 10);
    

    
  }
  
  move() {
    //player paddle movement
    keyPressed();
    if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW)) this.y+=l;
    if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)) this.y-=l;
    if (this.y>height-this.f) this.y=height-this.f;
    if (this.y<0) this.y=0;
      
    //opponent paddle movement
    this.z=this.h-30;
    if (this.z>height-60) this.z=height-60;
    if (this.z<0) this.z=0;
    
    //ball movement
    if (this.w > width-40) {
      this.speedX=-this.speedX;
    }

    if (this.h > height-10 || this.h<0) {
      this.speedY=-this.speedY;
    }
    this.w+=this.speedX;
    this.h+=this.speedY;
    } 

  collide() {
    hit = collideRectRect(30, this.y, 1, this.f, this.w, this.h, 10, 10);
    console.log(hit);
      
    if(hit) {
      this.speedX=-this.speedX;
      s=s+1;
      this.speedX=this.speedX*1.01;
      this.speedY=this.speedY*1.01;
      
        if (s === 5) {
          let u=(0);
    let p1=new Thing(0,0,0,u);
  things.push(p1);
          i=i+1;
          l=10;
  }
    }
    
    if (s === 5) this.f=100;
    if (s>5) this.f=100;
    if (s<5) this.f=60;
    
    if (this.w < -10) {
      gameClicks();
      if (s>b) b=s;
      this.w=width/2;
      this.h=height/2;
      this.y=0;
      this.speedX=5;
      this.speedY=5;
      s=0;
      l=5;
      if (i === 1) {
        things.pop();
      }
      i=0;

      
    }
  
    
    
    
  // print('colliding?', hit);
  }
  
  
}


function gameClicks() {
  mode = STARTSCREEN;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/p5.collide2d"></script>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Instead of adding a sketch in an external resource, please read [Runnable code snippets in questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: `ReferenceError: collideRectRect is not defined`, please don't forget about the external library

Answer (score 0):

I think if you take the time to simplify the cod to a minimal example the problem is pretty self evident: for each ball/paddle you only call `collideRectRect` for the positions if each paddle with it is associated ball. You do not call `collideRectRect` for each possible combination of ball and paddle. The design of the `Thing` class is confusing. You are encapsulating the state of a paddle and ball in a single class, but your question indicates that there should be interaction between all balls and all paddles, so it seems like the state of the paddles and balls should be stored separately and then you would need are pair of nested loops to check all ball/paddle combos for collision.

Here's a simplified version of your code that makes it easier to see the problem.

```js
let things=[];
let hit=false;
// score
let s=4;
// number of balls - 1?
let i=0;
// paddle movement speed
let l=5;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  let p1=new Thing(0,0,0,'#22ff2266');
  things.push(p1);
}

function draw() {
  background(80);
  
  for(let thing of things) {
    thing.move();
    thing.collide();
    thing.show();
  }
}

class Thing {
  constructor(x,y,z,c) {
    this.x=x;
    
    // player position
    this.y=y;
    
    // opponent position
    this.z=z;
    
    // size
    this.f=50;
    
    // color
    this.c=c;
    
    // ball position
    this.w=width/2;
    this.h=height/2;
    
    // ball velocity
    this.speedX=5;
    this.speedY=0;
  }
  
  show() {
    noStroke();
    fill(this.c);
    
    //player
    rect(0+20, this.y, 10, this.f);
    
    //opponent
    rect(width-30, this.z, 10, 60);
    
    //ball
    rect(this.w, this.h, 10, 10);
  }
  
  move() {
    //player paddle movement
    if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW)) this.y+=l;
    if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)) this.y-=l;
    
    // limit the position of the players paddle
    if (this.y>height-this.f) this.y=height-this.f;
    if (this.y<0) this.y=0;
      
    //opponent paddle movement
    this.z=this.h-30;
    if (this.z>height-60) this.z=height-60;
    if (this.z<0) this.z=0;
    
    //ball movement
    if (this.w > width-40) {
      this.speedX=-this.speedX;
    }

    if (this.h > height-10 || this.h<0) {
      this.speedY=-this.speedY;
    }
    
    this.w+=this.speedX;
    this.h+=this.speedY;
  } 

  collide() {
  
    // collideRectRect(x, y, width, height, x2, y2, width2, height2 )
    // check if the player paddle is colliding with the ball
    // each ball can only collide with its own paddle 
    hit = collideRectRect(30, this.y, 1, this.f, this.w, this.h, 10, 10);
    console.log(hit);
      
    if(hit) {
      this.speedX=-this.speedX;
      s=s+1;
      this.speedX=this.speedX*1.01;
      this.speedY=this.speedY*1.01;
      
      // When the player scores for the first time, add a new "thing"
      if (s === 5) {
        let p1=new Thing(0,0,0,'#ff222266');
        things.push(p1);
        i=i+1;
      }
    }
    
    if (this.w < -10) {
      // miss! reset ball position & speed
      this.w=width/2;
      this.h=height/2;
      this.y=0;
      this.speedX=5;
      this.speedY=5;
      
      s=0;
      if (i === 1) {
        // if there was an extra ball, remove it
        things.pop();
      }
      
      i=0;   
    }
   
  // print('colliding?', hit);
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/p5.collide2d"></script>
```